# TabContainer in BorderContainer not showing correctly

Tags: dojo

I am using a borderContainer with a fix width and centering in the center of my page (Use of a div around the bordercontainer).
Everything works fine until i add a TabContainer. All of a sudden i can not see my Tab's anymore. This goes as wel for IE as FF.
Is this a bug or something else? How could i work around this?

I'm using the latest release of dojo 1.4.3.

I've tried using borderContainer in borderContainer with no result.

Thnx
Stefaan

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inspect the DOM structure and see if the tab container is created or not. I think that your tab container has been created successfully, but you don't give it a size, so it appears to be zero width and zero height. Try to give a specified size to the tab container's DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

i does not work in any way as of the moment i define a height and width on the tabcontainer and try to **align in the center** my tabs disapear. The moment i remove the align="center" the tabcontainer is shown correctly

Here a give you an example (tabs are gone):

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" align="center">
      <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" tabStrip="true">
          <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Headlines" closable="false" >
            Lorem ipsum and all around...
          </div>
          <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Videos" closable="false">
            Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```